# Run MS access Function from python

Tags: python, vba, ms-access

Trying to run MS access function from python. Note that I have Access macro object with `RunCode` action that calls the function in the module 2. This macro is nameed as  `del_all_records()` , function has the same name too `del_all_records()`

This is my python code:

```
# search for directory
directory = r'C:/Users/' + username + /Documents/Customer/02.weekly Report/'

ac = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
ac.Visible=True
ac.OpenCurrentDatabase(directory +'/amazon.accdb')
ac.DoCmd.RunMacro('del_all_records()')
ac = None
```

This trace back error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "directory = r'C:/Users/' + username + /Documents/Customer/02.weekly Report/db_load.py", line 15, in <module>
    ac.DoCmd.RunMacro('del_all_records()')
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in RunMacro
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, 'You canceled the previous operation.', 'vbaac10.chm', 5738, -2146826287), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have the application open, you should be able to call the function directly:

```
ac.del_all_records()
```

Comment: it is not working it give me a new error `AttributeError: Access.Application.del_all_records`

Answer (score 0):

Code did not work until I did not change the path.

I have change in the path this

```
/
```

With this:

```
\\
```